# Proof involving Gamma distribution

Tags: statistics, gamma-distribution

X has Gamma(r, λ) distribution. Prove that Y=λX has Gamma(r,1) distribution.

I thought that you might be able to merely substitute the pdf for a Gamma(r, λ) distribution and then multiply that by lambda to then compare that to the pdf of a Gamma(r, 1) distribution. However this did not work. Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [rule for change of variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables), which for $Y=g(X)$, the density function of $Y$, denoted by $f(y)$ is
$$f(y)=f(x)\left|\frac{dX}{dY}\right|=f(g^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{dX}{dY}\right|$$ 
where $g^{-1}(y)$ denotes the inverse function.

So for $$f(x)=\Gamma(r,\lambda)=\frac{\lambda^r}{\Gamma(r)}x^{r-1}e^{-\lambda x}$$ and $Y=\lambda X$ you have
$$f(y)=\frac{\lambda^r}{\Gamma(r)}\left(\frac{y}{\lambda}\right)^{r-1}e^{-\lambda \frac{y}{\lambda}}\times\frac{1}{\lambda}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(r)}y^{r-1}e^{-y}=\Gamma(r,1)$$

Comment: That is amazing. How do I begin to learn how to figure it out like you did?

Comment: It takes hard work, and practice - there are rarely any shortcuts in life. So long as you put the work in it, you'll soon be figuring things out on your own!